# Wine: how do I remove the 'MY' from My Documents,

Tags: wine

I installed Wine and then a current windows program.

Although the files are located in the DOCUMENTS folder, when saving,... MY DOCUMENTS is displayed.

How do I remove the 'MY' from My Documents,...

Comment: isn't this actually a Windows thing and wine just uses that to be consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Is this XP, Win7 or 10? There appears to be a change in naming by the OS from Documents to My Documents. Also, is the My Documents folder possibly on another partition?

Try this: Rename as you did
Delete the desktop.ini hidden file in the document folder.

presto?

Comment: This is a WINE configuration.  MY docs, MY music, MY pictures,...
Childish shit.